# Windows defender detected and quarantined this: HTML/Phish.GR!MSR. Is there anything further I should do to check my computer has been affected?

Tags: malware, trojan

Windows defender detected the trojan **HTML/Phish.GR!MSR** and quarantined it.

After that, I scanned the computer with Malwarebytes and it found nothing.

I can find very little information online about this particular virus.  Is there anything else I should do to ensure it hasn't affected my system?

Comment: The term `Phish` plus `html` is usually an indicator that the malicious file is a html phishing email. In such a case the "attack target" is your brain not your computer.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/252657/windows-defender-catches-trojan-right-after-clean-install

Answer (score 1):

This detection looks like part of HTML/Phish family. These malicious softwares usually try to steal username and password.

If the page was quarantined and you have already ran the scan which found nothing, there isn't much you can do unless you see any other adverse behavior. (For example, for many people any of their preferred browser stops working.)

As a general recommendation, it is better to be vigilant about any social engineering techniques used online and keep strong passwords.